# Как расшифровать хэш-код?

Tags: криптография, хеширование

Помогите расшифровать вот этот код: `02013cec9690c354c748d25f9494fd9c`.

За ним скрывается число от 1  до 100.

Comment: Защитил вопрос от ответов и хочу напомнить: поле "ваш ответ" предназначено для публикации _решений_ вопроса топикстартера. Если вы хотите задать вопрос -- не нужно писать в эту тему, просто создайте новый вопрос (жми кнопку "Задать вопрос" справа вверху)

Answer (score 2):

Судя по всему, это md5, но там не число от 1 до 100 сокрыто. Ибо смотрим сюды: [тык](http://rslab.su/md5.php). 
Либо хешировали с солью какой-то.

**UPD:**
Вы бы хоть более-менее растолковали, что это и зачем, как генерировалось, так бы и ответ может быть даже нашли.

Answer (score 1):

Сходил в [крупнейшую БД хэшей](http://www.hashkiller.co.uk/md5-decrypter.aspx) (якобы ~44 млрд хэшей), сообщает:

> 02013cec9690c354c748d25f9494fd9c [Not found]

Так что взлом по радужным таблицам также не пройдет.

**Update**

Отвечая на вопрос ТС:

> Как расшифровать хэш-код?

Здесь все достаточно просто. Надо взять ломалку, достаточно [просто погуглить](brute force attack software) и в настройках задать схему, типа:

```
md5(password+salt)
```

Где `password` пробегает от 1 до 100, а `salt` все остальное. При длине соли 6 символов, количество комбинаций получится в районе 100 млрд. Хороший брутфорсер с использованием мощности графического процессора может перебирать в секунду 10 млн комбинаций, то есть за пару-тройку часов можно расколотить его.

Ну а если длина соли 7 символов - потребуется уже неделя, 8 символов - 4 месяца, ну дальше вы поняли. :) И то это при условии, что алгоритм именно такой, вполне может случиться алгоритм слегка другой, например:

```
md5(md5(password+salt/2)+salt/2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы уже в вопросе ответили на него.

Хеш по определению не возможно расшифровать, т.к. это не криптоалгоритм и подразумевает потерю данных. Можно брутить или по радужным табличкам попробовать прогнать, если, конечно, заранее известно как минимум, что это за алгоритм.

Answer (score 0):

Там 100% не просто `md5(цифра)`, и не `md5(md5(цифра))`, даже не `md5(md5(md5(цифра)))`,

и по любому там есть соль :)

```
foreach (range(1, 100) as $k => $v)
    if (md5($v) == '02013cec9690c354c748d25f9494fd9c')
        echo $v;
```

Ничего не вернуло :)